# Validating that an argument (which is a function) could be called with sibling arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm writing some higher-order-functions and am finding it difficult to write typings that validates that a function that is provided as an argument could be called with the other arguments provided.  Here's a super basic example:

```
function(myFunc, arg1, arg2) {
    return myFunc(arg1, arg2) // We want to verify that this is typesafe at compile time
}
```

And a more realistic example:

```
// Here's a higher order function that returns a function that alters input in some way
type algorithm = (input: number, options?: any) => number;
const createHandler = (algorithm: algorithm, options?) =>
  (input: number) => algorithm(input, options);

// This algorithm needs no 'options' configuration
const addOne = (input) => input + 1;
// This algorithm requires a specific 'options' configuration
interface PowerOptions { value: number; }
const power = (input: number, {value}: PowerOptions) => input ** value

// Now when I create these handlers, I'd like for the 'options' to be validated against the provided function
const addOneHandler = createHandler(addOne);
const squaredHandler = createHandler(power, { value: 2 });
const cubedHandler = createHandler(power, {});  // This should show a type error as the options are invalid for the algorithm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your basic example, you could proceed this way, with type inference, to check the type safety of the provided function ([check it on Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20a%20%3D%20function%20%3CU%2C%20V%3E(myFunc%3A%20(arg1%3A%20U%2C%20arg2%3A%20V)%20%3D%3E%20any%2C%20arg1%3A%20U%2C%20arg2%3A%20V)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20myFunc(arg1%2C%20arg2)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20doubleIfTrue%20%3D%20(arg1%3A%20number%2C%20arg2%3A%20boolean)%20%3D%3E%20arg2%20%3F%202%20*%20arg1%20%3A%20arg1%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(a(doubleIfTrue%2C%201%2C%20true))%0D%0Aconsole.log(a(doubleIfTrue%2C%201%2C%20%22hop%22)))):

```
const a = function <U, V>(myFunc: (arg1: U, arg2: V) => any, arg1: U, arg2: V) {
    return myFunc(arg1, arg2)
}

const doubleIfTrue = (arg1: number, arg2: boolean) => arg2 ? 2 * arg1 : arg1

console.log(a(doubleIfTrue, 1, true))  // Type OK
console.log(a(doubleIfTrue, 1, "hop")) // Wrong type: number and string provided
```

In this case, `U` and `V` types are inferred according to the arguments of the provided function.

---

But what you want to achieve would get a bit more complex. Based on your code, I could sort something out ([check it on Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20algorithm%3COPT%20%3D%20null%3E%20%3D%20(input%3A%20number%2C%20options%3F%3A%20OPT)%20%3D%3E%20number%3B%0D%0Atype%20algorithmOptions%3CA%3E%20%3D%20A%20extends%20algorithm%3Cinfer%20OPT%3E%20%3F%20OPT%20%3A%20null%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20createHandler%20%3D%20%3CA%20extends%20algorithm%3Cany%3E%3E(algorithm%3A%20A%2C%20options%3A%20algorithmOptions%3CA%3E)%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20(input%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20algorithm(input%2C%20options)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Algorithms%0D%0Aconst%20addOne%3Aalgorithm%20%3D%20(input%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20input%20%2B%201%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20PowerOptions%20%7B%20value%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20power%3Aalgorithm%3CPowerOptions%3E%20%3D%20(input%3A%20number%2C%20%7Bvalue%7D)%20%3D%3E%20input%20**%20value%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Handlers%0D%0Aconst%20squaredHandler%20%3D%20createHandler(power%2C%20%7B%20value%3A%202%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20correct%0D%0Aconst%20addOneHandler%20%3D%20createHandler(addOne%2C%20null)%3B%20%2F%2F%20correct%20if%20a%20second%20argument%20is%20provided%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20addOneHandlerFailing%20%3D%20createHandler(addOne%2C%20%7B%20value%3A%202%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20wrong%20because%20an%20argument%20is%20provided%0D%0Aconst%20squaredHandlerFailing1%20%3D%20createHandler(power%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20wrong%20because%20of%20argument%20interface%20not%20respected%0D%0Aconst%20squaredHandlerFailing2%20%3D%20createHandler(power)%3B%20%2F%2F%20wrong%20because%20no%20argument%20provided)):

```
type algorithm<OPT = null> = (input: number, options?: OPT) => number;
type algorithmOptions<A> = A extends algorithm<infer OPT> ? OPT : null

const createHandler = <A extends algorithm<any>>(algorithm: A, options: algorithmOptions<A>) =>
(input: number) => algorithm(input, options);

// Algorithms
const addOne:algorithm = (input: number) => input + 1;
interface PowerOptions { value: number; }
const power:algorithm<PowerOptions> = (input: number, {value}) => input ** value

// Handlers
const squaredHandler = createHandler(power, { value: 2 }); // correct
const addOneHandler = createHandler(addOne, null); // correct if a second argument is provided

const addOneHandlerFailing = createHandler(addOne, { value: 2 }); // wrong because an argument is provided
const squaredHandlerFailing1 = createHandler(power, {}); // wrong because of argument interface not respected
const squaredHandlerFailing2 = createHandler(power); // wrong because no argument provided
```

With some [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) to retrieve the algorithm argument. But maybe I went too far, and that you could find a way simpler approach

Another thing: to my knowledge, it seems that the options argument of `createHandler` couldn't be optional in some case and mandatory in some other, without turning the example into something more complex.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the well-written answer! Your answer is a great start, I am okay with always requiring an argument, but unfortunately the solution falls short in that you can provide `null` in place of the require options: `const squaredHandlerFailing3 = createHandler(power, null); // BAD, because no argument provided but no error
`.

I'll keep experimenting and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: Ah, I see now that adding `"strictNullChecks": true` to my `tsconfig.json` makes it all work as expected! Great, thanks! This requires a bit of learning on my part to fully understand _why_ this works, but it definitely does the trick! Thanks agains!

Comment: Note that the `options?` input on the `algorithm` type also had to be changed to `options` to allow for `strictNullChecks` to work (destructuring `options` breaks otherwise)

Comment: @alukach you're welcome! Also, don't hesitate to use Typescript Playground: changing the options is very easy from there